# Dynamic Programming for a variant of the coin exchange

Tags: dynamic-programming, coin-change

I am interested in solving a variant of the coin exchange problem. Recall the formal definition of the coin exchange problem:

Given a value *N*, if we want to make change for *N* cents, and we have infinite supply of each of *S = {S1, S2, .. , Sm}* integral-valued coins, how many ways can we make the change? The order of coins doesn’t matter. For example, for *N* = 4 and *S = {1,2,3}*, there are four solutions: {1,1,1,1},{1,1,2},{2,2},{1,3}. So output should be 4. For *N* = 10 and *S = {2, 5, 3, 6}*, there are five solutions: {2,2,2,2,2}, {2,2,3,3}, {2,2,6}, {2,3,5} and {5,5}. So the output should be 5. [See here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/) for further detail.

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/), one can find a tabulation-DP-based solution for this problem. This solution is based on the following recurrence relation:

```
count(S, m, n) = count(S, m - 1, n) + count(S, m, n - S[m - 1]);
```

With base cases:

```
count(S, m, n < 0) = 0
count(S, m, n = 0) = 1
count(S, m <= 0, n >= 1) = 0
```

Intuitively, this recurrence relation defines a problem as the solution to two sub-problems: Those in where we discard coins, and those for which we assume the coins a progressively used once at the time.

**Question**: How can I modify this recurrence relation to count the number of ways we can sum to *N* disregarding order and with an even number of summands? For example, for *N* = 4 and *S = {1,2,3}*, there are four solutions total (disregarding order): {1,1,1,1},{1,1,2},{2,2},{1,3}, but only 3 of them have an even number of summands, i.e. {1,1,1,1},{2,2},{1,3}.

**Previous research**: At first I thought I could double the requested sum for the case of discarding coins, and requesting that each coin is consumed twice for the cases in where we would use some of the coins, i.e.:

```
count(S, m, n) = count(S, m - 1, 2*n) + count(S, m, n - 2*S[m - 1]);
```

This works for some sample cases, but it does not work. Any hints?

Comment: I guess that you can use two separate functions for using Odd and Even count:
`o(S,m,n)= o(m-2, n)+e(m, n-s[m-1])`
and 
`e(S,m,n)= e(m-2, n)+o(m, n-s[m-1])`
with base:
`o(S, m, n < 0) = 0
o(S, m, n = 0) = 0
o(S, m <= 0, n >= 1) = 0`
and 
`e(S, m, n < 0) = 0
e(S, m, n = 0) = 1
e(S, m <= 0, n >= 1) = 0
`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a flag to the recursion which is the parity of the number of summands used so far.

When using a summand you flip the flag (`S(n-v[m],m,!parity)`).

Base cases are:

```
n=0 parity=0 -> 1

n=0 parity=1 -> 0

n<0 or m<0 (array is 0-indexed) -> 0
```

Below is the recursive function in c++. Ofcourse you need to memoize it for it to work on bigger values.

```
int S(int n,int m,bool parity)
{
    if (n==0)
    {
        if (parity==1)
            return 0;
        else 
            return 1;
    }
    if (m<0 || n<0)
        return 0;
    return S(n,m-1,parity)+S(n-v[m],m,!parity);
}
```